# Printing 2 sides per page does not work anymore since update to 13.10

Tags: printing, libreoffice, pdf, gedit, evince

I used to often print documents with 2 pages per side to save paper. Since I have updated to Ubuntu 13.10, this no longer works properly.

The problem seems to be with the rotation. Because if I select 4 pages per side, which does not involve rotation, things are fine.

The problem exists at least when printing from Evince, LibreOffice and Gedit. With Evince, the problem can be circumvented by requesting a preview first. The preview is fine and can then be printed.
In Gedit however, the preview shows only one page per side, although rotated correctly. There is no option to print from the preview.

I have verified the problem on two workstations, one with a clean install of 13.10 and one upgraded from 13.04. And on 2 printers, both Brother. An MFC-7440N and an HL4150CDN.

Can anyone verify this problem? Or better yet, tell me how to fix it?